# P4 Plugin failed in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I am trying to set up a job in Jenkins using this p4 plugin. I successfully installed the plugin. While I am trying to run perforce commands in execute shell I got below exception.

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6165069639422088214.sh
+ echo 'Trunk Release is r2017.1.0'
Trunk Release is r2017.1.0
++ /usr/local/perforce/p4 -P E208C3B005AB1F8E7C138F7156F857EC counter cos_sso_trunk_build_number
User jenkins doesn't exist.
+ BLD_NUM=
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have included P4 Configuration, Its working fine. But above error is when I will try P4 commands in console earlier Perforce plugin (old) its working fine

Answer (score 0):

It's expecting an account for the user "jenkins". Either create an account for that user, or use an existing user.

On the Configure page, under Source Code Management-->Perforce Software Perforce Credentials, select Add to add the user information.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have added those details. Its working fine. But above error is when I will try P4 commands in console